# GM_xmlhttpRequest POST request not working cross-domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

I'm running a script in Tampermonkey, and I'm trying to use the GM_xmlhttpRequest method to send a POST request cross-domain. However It's not working for me. In the console I just get normal cross-origin the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load [domain1]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin [domain2] is
>   therefore not allowed access.

It's my understanding that the whole point of the GM request method is that it supports cross-domain unlike XMLHttpRequest(). So I'm not seeing why this will not work as it should.
Here is the gist of what I'm doing:

```
// @match      https://[domain2]
// @grant      GM_xmlhttpRequest

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://[domain1]/exmaple.php",
    data: formData,            
    onload: function(response) {}        
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
})
```

Maybe I'm missing something simple or I have the wrong idea

edit: I suppose I should note that the above code is nested inside a different normal XMLHttpRequest in case that would affect it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the "Unsafe window retrieval" setting in Tampermonkey just needed to be set to Native. Seems to be working now